# jQuery - Change elements with the same id tags class name dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dynamic

I have a structure like this

```
        <div class="dynamic" id="thumbnail-div">
            <p id="thumbnail-p">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/circle.GIF" alt="Example Number 1 For Display Case" name="Example Number 1 For Display Case" class="dynamic" id="thumbnail-img" />
                </a>
            </p>
        </div>
```

There are multiples of that html structure above so there could be like 10, 20, 50, etc. Now what I am trying to do is have jQuery change the classes to all the elements with the id of "thumbnail-div" to something like thumb1, thumb2, thumb3, etc.. so they should count up depending on how many there are. I cannot find a way to achieve this and after a lot of research I have found nothing helpful. Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Um. You cannot have multiple `id` 's on a page, use `classes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to having duplicated **ID's** on your page ..

I am afraid if you try to access these elements with ID it will only retrieve `the first element with that ID`..

Lets say all your div's in Question has the .dynamic class.. Then you can do something like this

```
$('div.dynamic').each(function(i){

     $(this).addClass('thumb' + (i+1));   // Add Class
     $(this).attr('id' , 'thumb' + (i+1));  // Set id for each div 
});
```

[Check FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/9uW2V/)

Comment: What if I wanted to set id instead? Is this possible?

Comment: for id do this  $(this).attr('id' , 'thumb' + (i+1))

Comment: Would it be smarter just making my class "thumbnail-div thumb1" so on and so forth? So then I wouldn't even have to touch ids. What would you recommend?

Comment: The first think is use a class instead of id's.. You don't need the id's in the first place <div class ="thumbnail-div > is sufficient for all the div's , and then you can add the classes to them..

Answer (score 0):

First of all you shouldn't have any duplicated id's on a page, so you should change them all into the class so they should be `<di class = "dynamic thumbnail-div">` and the jQuery to get all of them on the page then iterate through and remove the class name of thumbnail-div and change it to thumb1 thumb2 etc would be something like

```
$('.thumbnail-div').each(function(index) {
    $(this).removeClass('thumbnail-div');
    $(this).addClass('thumb' + index);
}
```

I'm pretty sure this should work. If you wnated to remove the class name and then add an id since now they will all be unique you could use `$(this).attr('id', 'thumb' + index);` instead of the .addClass line

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use elements with duplicated `id`.

Let say if you use `thumbnail-div` as `class` for the `divs` then you can probably do this

```
$(".thumbnail-div").each(function(index){
    $(this).addClass('thumb'+(index+1)); 
    // or set id $(this).attr('id' , 'thumb' + (index+1)); 
    alert($(this).attr('class'));
});​
```

**[Live Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/zSUsQ/)**

Answer (score 0):

Answer is here http://jsfiddle.net/A9SfJ/

```
$('.dynamic').addClass('thumb1').removeClass('dynamic');
```